# VPN over Shadowsocks: DNS not working

Tags: virtualbox, vpn, dns, openvpn, ubuntu-18.04

I am currently in China. Usually I use Shadowsocks or a VPN to access the outside/filtered internet. However, due to some requirements I need to access the outside internet by using VPN over Shadowsocks. I found some instructions on the internet and by following these I can indeed connect to the VPN server of my VPN service provider over Shadowsocks. The problem that I have now is that in a browser no website is loaded. I eventually found out that the reason for that is that the DNS does not work.

Here is what happens:
When I enter the domain of my server nothing happens. However, if I enter my IP address the website is loaded without any problems.

This is my setup:

1. MacOS runs a Shadowsocks connection
2. A Virtual-Box runs Ubuntu 18 and openvpn
3. I connect from Ubuntu 18 via the Host-System (macOS and SS) to the internet.

This is my openvpn config file I am using (extract):

```
dev tun
fast-io
persist-key
persist-tun
nobind
remote germany-frankfurt-1-ca-version-2.vpn-server.com 443
proto tcp-client

remote-random
pull
comp-lzo no
tls-client
verify-x509-name Server name-prefix
ns-cert-type server
key-direction 1
route-method exe
route-delay 2
tun-mtu 1500
#fragment 1300
mssfix 1450
verb 3
cipher AES-256-CBC
keysize 256
auth SHA512
sndbuf 524288
rcvbuf 524288
auth-user-pass "/home/ubuntu/evpn-openvpn-config-files/vpn-user.pass"
socks-proxy 10.0.2.2 1080
```

Since my Mac is the host of the Virtual Machine I need to replace `socks-proxy 127.0.0.1 1080` with `socks-proxy 10.0.2.2 1080`.

Does anybody know how this DNS problem can be resolved?

Comment: A [Support answer](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-android/issues/1644) offered this workaround that might help : "A workaround is using Apps VPN mode, and excluding the browser that you want to use with internal web sites". Not using the software I can't help more than that.

Comment: Please do not add "solved" to the title. Accepting the best answer is the way to indicate the question is solved. I believe you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the original DNS server was for some reason not reachable. Therefore, modified `/etc/resolv.conf` and added the following line (Google public nameservers):

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

After that I executed `sudo service networking restart`. Now it works fine.